# GCDWebServer fails to comile when CocoaLumberjak is included in project

Tags: cocoapods, gcdwebserver, cocoalumberjack

When using cocoapods, with those 2 libs:

```
  pod "GCDWebServer", "3.3.2"
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '2.2.0'
```

Project fails to compile, as GCDW does not link to LumberJack (even optionally).
Adding Lumberjack to "Linked Grameworks and Libraries" as optional, for GCDWS pod fixes the issue, but it is only a workaround, as each 
`pod install` resets the state, making it pain in the a$$ to work with, and impossible to have it build by CI env.

Any ideas of how to solve that?

BTW - GCDWebServer guys, why you have dissabled issues on GitHUb!?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer/pull/256. Use this in your podspec:

```
pod 'GCDWebServer/CocoaLumberjack'
```